# Does the gap between a vacuum tube cathode and anode influence the current?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, acceleration

My understanding is that a vacuum tube can act as a voltage controlled current source, but the question I have is if the length of the gap between the cathode and anode has any effect on the current at a given acceleration voltage.

Comment: The field controls the current.